# Listview work on ios but does not work on android

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native

```
[enter image description here][1]   
[Android listview nothing appears][1]
[ios listview works fine][2]
[ios listview detail screen works fine.][3]
```

I’m developing the both iOS and android APL using React Native.

React Native is great, and I would like to develop with React Native.

Currently I have one strange error.

Basically I use [react-native-hackathon-starter](https://github.com/dabit3/react-native-hackathon-starter) for TAB control.

In one TAB environment, I added list-detail function (Master-Detail something like).
I made list screen and detail screen on one TAB, did well on iOS but not on android.

Attached screen shot shows iOS work fine with list and detail screen but android does not display list at all.

react-native-hackathon-starter need the following structure.
MoreRootContainer.js ➡　MoreNav.js goes to TAB class.

This time I added  TAB class to another Navigator for list class(screen) and detail class(screen) like as follows.

```
<Navigator
// Default to list route
initialRoute={{name: 'list1'}}
// Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>
 Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
// Pass a route mapper functions
renderScene={RouteMapper}
/>
```

This approach is fine on iOS but not on android.

Is there any reason why iOS is OK but not android?

Go back to basic usage of Navigator,
above usage of Navigator is allowed or not?

I would like to confirm of usage of Navigator.

My reference list-detail function is as follows.

React Native List App Complete How-To Guide
http://rationalappdev.com/react-native-list-app-complete-how-to-guide/#what-are-we-building

Thanks

Shoji

Comment: my reference is 'React Native List App Complete How-To Guide'
by Konstantin Shkut              http://rationalappdev.com/react-native-list-app-complete-how-to-guide/#what-are-we-building

Comment: '  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar title="Rera" />
        <Image source={require('../images/rera.png')}
        style={{width: 60, height: 60 />
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          style={styles.listview}/>

  _renderRow = (movie) => {
    return (
      <Row
        movie={movie}
        onPress={()=>{
  
          this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'movie',
            movie: movie, '

Answer (score 0):

I’m developing the both iOS and android APL using React Native.

I could not believe this phenomenon because React Native is for iOS and android..

I spend a few days to debug this.

Futunately I found the following info.
ReactNative-0.38,a warning,'useNativeDriver' is not supported #276 
https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigation/issues/276

This article imply ReactNative-0.37 OK.
I tried go back to ReactNative from 38 to 36 and it works fine BOTH platform.

If there is someone who is struggling on this kind problem,  this info will be some help.

Thanks

Shoji